# Controller in Directive is not getting read

Tags: angularjs

It prints `1`, but doesn't print `2` and `3`. What is wrong here?

```
"use strict";

console.log('1');

module.exports = TestDirective;

TestDirective.$inject = [];

function TestDirective() {

    console.log('2');

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            user: "=",
            onComplete: "&",
            hideSubmitButton: "=?"
        },
        templateUrl: "/test.html",
        controller: TestCtrl4,
        controllerAs: "testCtrl4",
        bindToController: true
    };
}

TestCtrl4.$inject = ["$log", "$scope"];

function TestCtrl4($log, $scope) {
    var vm = this;

    console.log('3');
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without more context. It looks like you've defined the directive and controller functions, but you need to "register" the actual directive with Angular before it can be used in a template.Here's a JS Fiddle that uses your directive and controller: https://jsfiddle.net/yr3qwszj/3/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Upon further reading, I discovered that `"use strict"` should not have affected the behavior of your `console.log()` statements. You just needed to call `TestDirective();`

---

It might be that, because you are in strict mode the code in the function body is not being evaluated until it is called.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/strict-mode-javascript

```
"use strict";  
function testFunction(){  
    var testvar = 4;  
    return testvar;  
}  

// This causes a syntax error.  
testvar = 5;
```

I would test this by removing `"use strict"` or by calling your function, like:

```
const testVar = TestDirective();
```